# How to handle async errors in express using express-async-handler package?

Tags: express, async-await, middleware

I'm using the npm package "express-async-handler" to avoid using try/catch blocks in my route controller functions along with Express default error handler middleware. I'm also using mongoose models in the controller.

Controller code:

```
const getBootcamp = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.findById(req.params.id);

  if (bootcamp) {
    // if item found (WORKS)
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: bootcamp });
  } else {
   //if item not found (WORKS) **DUE TO AN INVALID ID WHICH IS IN CORRECT FORMAT e.g. "6414eec6e5db192719b46943"**
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error('Bootcamp not found!');
  }

  //* How do I handle the situation in which an id has been passed but is not in the correct mongooseId format e.g. "6414eec6e5db192719b46943000000000000000"
});
```

Express Default Error Handler code:

```
const errorHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode;

  res.status(statusCode).json({ success: false, msg: error.message });
};

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

**I have included the error middleware using app.use() after all the routes so it is configured properly.**

I read that I need to call next(err) to send the error to the errorMiddleware but in the code shared above anything added after the else block with become unreachable code.

Comment: The point of `asyncHandler` is to catch uncaught rejections (like from your `await`) and send them to your Express error handler.  Express, by itself, will catch synchronous exceptions, but not promise rejections.  If you're using `asyncHandler`, you can just `throw` and error and it will go to your Express errorhandler automatically, even from your `async` request handler.

Comment: read the last paragraph again please.  If i try to throw an error after the else block, it won't be reachable. I can make all the scenarios work with try/catch block but not with this current selection.

Comment: I need to throw an error so that i can pass in a custom message which can be read in the error middleware

Comment: Why throw an error after the else block?  There's no point to that because that is indeed unreachable.  If you want to catch a specific error from the `await Bootcamp.findById(req.params.id);`, then put a `try/catch` around that and handle the error yourself in the `catch` block.  You can rethrow in the catch with the specific error you want and then `asyncHandler` will route that to your Express error handler with your custom error.  This is just normal error handling in Javascript.  If you want to custom handle the error or convert it to something else, you `try/catch` is locally.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using try/catch altogether. I have found a solution to the problem by checking the type of error thrown (CastError) and error kind (ObjectId) and then simply returning a custom json response from the error middleware. My objective was to catch an invalid mongoose id and this approach does get the job done, however, I feel there may be a solution in which something can be done in the controller itself.

Comment: No.  The ONLY way you're going to process a rejection from an `await` in the controller is with a `try/catch` or a `.catch()`.  I don't know why you're trying to avoid that if you want to handle the error in the controller.  That's how Javascript works.  I repeat what I said above.  If you want to locally custom handle a rejection from an `await`, you use a `try/catch` around it.  That's how the language works.

Comment: You can indeed detect the specific error in your generic handler if that's sufficient to solve your problem.  But, if you want to handle it in the controller use either a `try/catch` around the `await` or add a `.catch()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was able to successfully accomplish this with a try/catch block but using a try/catch block again and again in every single route controller function just doesn't seem right. I was just messing around with this approach hoping a find a more elegant and less complicated solution than what's available online.

Comment: If you're trying to do the same error checking over and over in different controller methods, then just create a utility function that does the find and the error checking for you and then converts it into the error you want.  This is GENERIC coding practice and has nothing to do with `asyncHandler` or anything else.  If you have the same code over and over, then encapsulate that code in a shared function that you can use from multiple places.

Comment: For some reason, people seem to forget that controller methods or request handlers are just normal JS functions and you encapsulate shared code in functions and call them from multiple controller methods or from multiple request handlers just like you would do if this was regular functional programming outside of Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const errorHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
  if (error.name === 'CastError' && error.kind === 'ObjectId') {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, msg: 'Invalid Id format' });
  }

  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode;

  res.status(statusCode).json({ success: false, msg: error.message });
};

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

By making the above modification to the error middleware I was able to check for an invalid mongoose id and send a custom json response.

Now 3 conditions are being handled:

1. Query executed and data was sent successfully
2. Query failed because the mongoose id was invalid (but in proper format)
3. Query failed because the mongoose id was not in proper format and hence invalid

The first 2 are handled by the controller and the last by the error handler middle.